# How do you Modify TextBox Control Tab Stops

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When you use a Windows Forms TextBox, the default number of tab stops (spaces) is 8. How do you modify this?

Comment: Works fine, but you forgot to say the value in measured in 'dialog template units' (whatever they are). `int[]={16}` give a tab of four spaces with my font.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First add the following namespace

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

Then add the following after the class declaration:

```
private const int EM_SETTABSTOPS = 0x00CB;
[DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr h, 
 int msg, 
 int wParam, 
 int [] lParam);
```

Then add the following to the Form_Load event:

```
// define value of the Tab indent 
int[] stops = {16}; 
// change the indent 
SendMessage(this.textBox1.Handle, EM_SETTABSTOPS, 1, stops);
```